# How to attach a resource file to an existing executable file?

Tags: delphi, resources

I have a resource file(.RES) and i want to add it into an existing executable file without recompiling and using the IDE! is it possible?

**Edit**

And how to extract the resource file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your question is, if you can add a resource to a existing exe  file, yes it is possible. To do this you must use the [`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which can `add, delete, or replace a resource in a portable executable (PE) file`.

**update**

### Here you have a sample code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Classes,
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

procedure UpdateExeResource(Const Source,Dest:string);
var
  Stream     : TFileStream;
  hDestRes   : THANDLE;
  lpData     : Pointer;
  cbData     : DWORD;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(Source,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  try
    Stream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    cbData:=Stream.Size;
    if cbData>0 then
    begin
      GetMem(lpData,cbData);
      try
        Stream.Read(lpData^, cbData);
        hDestRes:= BeginUpdateResource(PChar(Dest), False);
        if hDestRes <> 0 then
          if UpdateResource(hDestRes, RT_RCDATA,'DATA',0,lpData,cbData) then
          begin
            if not EndUpdateResource(hDestRes,FALSE) then RaiseLastOSError
          end
          else
          RaiseLastOSError
        else
        RaiseLastOSError;
      finally
        FreeMem(lpData);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    UpdateExeResource('C:\Users\Dexter\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\Debug\Win32\Data.txt','C:\Users\Dexter\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects\Debug\Win32\project86.exe');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Colin Wilson's excellent [Resource Utilities](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/delphi_2006.htm).

I'm using this simple console application to add a resource to an executable using his tools:

```
program AddResource; 

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  unitNtModule,
  unitResFile,
  unitResourceRCData;

  procedure AddRes(exeName, resName: string);
  var
    exeModule: TNTModule;
    resFile  : TResModule;
  begin
    if ExtractFileExt(exeName) = '' then
      exeName := ChangeFileExt(exeName, '.exe');
    exeModule := TNTModule.Create;
    try
      exeModule.LoadFromFile(exeName);
      resFile := TResModule.Create;
      resFile.LoadFromFile(resName);
      exeModule.AddResource(resFile.ResourceDetails[0]);
      exeModule.SaveToFile(exeName);
    finally FreeAndNil(exeModule); end;
  end; { AddRes }

begin
  if ParamCount <> 2 then
    Writeln('Usage: AddResource <exe file> <resource file>')
  else
    AddRes(ParamStr(1), ParamStr(2));
end.
```

Answer (score 4):

This is my answer : (Thank you PRUZ)

```
Uses Classes, Windows, SysUtils, Dialogs;

Type
  TBuffer = Array[0..0] of Byte;
  PBuffer = ^TBuffer;

Var
  FS             : TFileStream;
  ResourceHandle : THandle;
  DataLength     : DWord;
  Data           : PBuffer;
  Ok             : Boolean;

Begin
   ResourceHandle := BeginUpdateResource(pChar('d:\someexefile.exe'), False);
   IF (ResourceHandle <> 0) Then
   Begin
      FS := TFileStream.Create('d:\somebitmap.bmp', fmOpenRead);
      FS.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      DataLength := FS.Size;
      GetMem(Data, DataLength);
      FS.Read(Data^, DataLength);
      FS.Free;

      Ok := True;
      IF (not UpdateResource(ResourceHandle, RT_RCDATA, pChar('MyNewResource'), LANG_SYSTEM_DEFAULT{MakeLangID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL)}, Data, DataLength)) Then Ok := False;

      IF (not EndUpdateResource(ResourceHandle, False)) Then Ok := False;

      IF (Ok) Then ShowMessage('Update of resources successful!')
         Else ShowMessage('Update of resources failed!');

      FreeMem(Data);
   End;
End.
```

Reference : http://www.delphi3000.com