# Delphi : How to read image from ".res file", not the embedded resource

Tags: delphi

Does anyone know how to **read** an **image** from .res **file** on disk, using a Delphi program?

**Please note** that i'm asking about reading an image from .res file on disk,
and not about embedding resources to Delphi Application and read a resource file linked into an executable.

I mean :

1. Filename and path to a .res file on disk, open the .res file and decode it enough to...
2. Locate the Image.
3. Load the image

**not** something like this :

```
{$R resfile.res}    

blablabla.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'IMAGE_NAME');
```

Thank you for advanced help.

Comment: Related: [How to attach a resource file to an existing executable file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054300)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The open-source [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) (written in Delphi) contains the necessary code to do this (as well as read/edit resources from executables, DLLs, OCX modules etc).
You'll be able to pull what you need from that!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I've been trying that base on [TResModule](http://www.hackchina.com/en/r/48681/unitResFile.pas__html) component used on XN Resource Editor. **That's the only solution as far as i know**. But the problem is my app's size grow bigger. Any other solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the code hasn't been updated in a *long* time, so a little recoding wouldn't be such a bad idea.

Comment: No more downloads from the site.  And i subtly recall some talks, that some community wanted to overtake and continue XNRE