# How to add settings and make then be built into an existing exe file in Delphi

Tags: delphi, exe

lets say that I have a program, that is modifying registry in Windows. User can chose what keys will be changed. After this he will click "generate" to create new exe file which will do its job depending on user choices.
How can I achieve that "exe generating" by clicking generate?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: one weird options would be to store settings in exe's Extended Attributes or Alternate Data Streams

Comment: ADS not available on all filesystems

Comment: While altering the EXE is relatively easy - there are many ways, like just having a marker in the EXE at the beginning of a record, through resources, and other appendings, the modern world will frown on any exe modifying itself. For starters, you need admin permissions. Then the anti-virus software will trigger an alert as the checksum changed. Then the code signing certificate will fail. Providing the user with a way to save to an INI file or similar is probably better nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to have two EXEs. One is your main app, and the second is the app that changes the registry. Now you have to append some data to get a copy of your secondary app using your main app and append the data that specifies what keys to change.
One way is to use resources. Use your main app to append required data as resources to your target exe (The compiled to-be-generated exe).
Your target exe file should check and load data resource from its own executable file and retrieve the required data.

You might find these links useful:
[How to attach a resource file to an existing executable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054300/how-to-attach-a-resource-file-to-an-existing-executable-file)

And how to retrieve the resource in your target exe:
http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/embed_resources_2.htm